# Dark mode not working properly in ASP.NET MVC project with Tailwind and Flowbite

Tags: c#, asp.net, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using Tailwind CSS in my ASP.NET MVC project but the dark mode stops working properly when I install Flowbite. The expected behavior is for the color mode (light or dark) to be selected automatically when I switch my OS color mode. It does work like that when I'm using only Tailwind, but when I install Flowbite for some reason it stops working. I'm able to toggle manually for light and dark mode, but I can't make the automatic toggle based on system preferences.

I installed both Tailwind and Flowbite with npm, and in the case of Flowbite, I've manually put the `flowbite.min.js` inside the `wwwroot/lib` folder because I couldn't make it work through the `node_modules` folder.

This is what I have in the `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './Pages/**/*.cshtml',
        './Views/**/*.cshtml',
        './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require('flowbite/plugin')
    ],
}
```

And this is what I have in the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "css:build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./wwwroot/css/site.css -o ./wwwroot/css/styles.css --minify"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flowbite": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

I've already tried adding to the tailwind.config.js both `darkMode: 'class'` and `darkMode: 'media'` and it didn't work. Both of these configs apparently did nothing. And I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Flowbite.